# MEAN Stack - ng-click inside of ng-repeat not working with database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

```js
 //app.js

 var blogApp = angular.module('BlogApp', []);  //angular module setup, matches ng-app from index.html
 

 blogApp.controller('BlogController', function($scope, $http){   //have to add $http if your going to use http (inject the dependancy)

  $scope.createPost = createPost;  //grabbing createPost from index.html (binding)
  $scope.deletePost = deletePost;  //map deletePost from index.html

  function init(){   //put everything that happens when site first loads in init function, good practice
   getAllPosts();
  }

  init();      //call init function to show all database posts
  


  function getAllPosts(){       //retrieve latest blogposts

   $http.get("/api/blogpost").success(function (posts){  //if its successfull, send posts back to client

    $scope.posts = posts; //send back to client using $scope

   });

  }


  function createPost(post){    //taking post object from ng-model in index.html

   console.log(post);           //displaying post information in console log on html site
   $http.post("/api/blogpost", post).success(getAllPosts);  //push 'post' data to api/blogpost url, also call function getAllPosts when posting new post
   console.log(postId);
  }

  function deletePost(postId){    //deletePost is the same name as in index file for ng-click
    console.log(postId);
    $http.delete("/api/blogpost/"+postId).success(getAllPosts);   //delete just one post with specific id, without + postId it would delete all posts


  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
<h1>Blog</h1> 

<input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
<textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea/>
<button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>


<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
<h2>
 {{post.title}}
 <a ng-click="deletPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
</h2>
<em>{{post.posted}}</em>
<p>
 {{post.body}}
</p>
</div>

 {{posts}} 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, my ng-click button is not calling my deletePost() function.  Been trying to figure this out for hours have no idea why it is not working.  Get absolutely no response when clicking the glyphicon.  Tried button as well still no response.  Anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your description you called it `deletePost()` but in your code it says `deletPost(post._id)`. Typo?

Comment: Thank you yes it was typo, must have been looking at this screen too long.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working properly because of the spelling error:

```
ng-click="deletPost(post._id)"
```

to

```
ng-click="deletePost(post._id)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cannot believe I didn't see that.  At least now I'm an expert in ng-click within ng-repeat with all the research I just did haha.

Comment: Haha true. Have a great future